# Unable to print table with kable and for loop

Tags: r, r-markdown

This prints as a regular code but not at all using rmarkdown. The problem may be located in the condensed and styling options of the code.. Any thoughts?

```
{r printing,echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, results='asis'}


library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(dotwhisker)
library(broom)


kbl <- function (df) {
  cat("\n\n")
  df2<-kable(df) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "condensed"))
  print(df2)
  cat("\n\n")
}


df <- mtcars
nested_inter <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% 
  nest() ## groups all the data by the sub series
nested_inter <- nested_inter  %>% 
  mutate (model =  map(data, 
                       ~lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + drat + hp +wt , data = .)))


  for(i in seq(nrow(nested_inter))) {
    kbl(glance(nested_inter$model[[i]]))
    t1<- nested_inter$model[[i]] %>% broom::tidy() 
    kbl(t1)
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this more of what you were looking for? Your code example didn't have the proper Rmarkdown syntax.

````
---
title: "Kable output"
output: html_document
---
```{r printing,echo=FALSE, message = FALSE, warning =     FALSE,cache=FALSE, results='asis'}


library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(dotwhisker)
library(broom)


kbl <- function (df) {
  cat("\n\n")
  df2<-kable(df) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options =     c("striped", "condensed"))
  print(df2)
  cat("\n\n")
}


df <- mtcars
nested_inter <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% 
  nest() ## groups all the data by the sub series
nested_inter <- nested_inter  %>% 
  mutate (model =  map(data, 
                       ~lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + drat + hp     +wt , data = .)))


for(i in seq(nrow(nested_inter))) {
  kbl(glance(nested_inter$model[[i]]))
  t1<- nested_inter$model[[i]] %>% broom::tidy() 
  kbl(t1)
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It looks great here bu when I run it locally it generates a single file that is empty and 4-5 different tabs (Not included in the main file)

Comment: Did you copy and paste my answer into a new Rmarkdown file? mine renders into a single HTML page with all the tables.